# PHP Wait then Generate a Tag or Link

Tags: php

I looking for php code in which hyper-link will not show for certain amount of time after that it will generate, using PHP with coundown.

```
<a href="<?php echo $download_link; ?>" class="btn btn-primary">
<?php echo $Download_Name; ?>
</a>
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is *not* a code writing service. 
We are always glad to help and support new coders but you need to help yourself first. 
You are expected to try to write the code yourself.
Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Do you have any code yet? For me this seems more like a JavaScript that a PHP-issue.

Comment: not really but i m looking for someone help

Answer (score 0):

Generate the following HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function handleTime() {
        var time = parseInt(document.getElementById('time'));
        function finish() {
            document.getElementById("container").innerHTML = '<a href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49852073/php-wait-then-generate-a-tag-or-link">Some link</a>';
        }
        if (time === 0) {
            finish();
        } else {
            var myInterval = setInterval(function() {
                if (!(--time)) {
                    clearInterval(myInterval);
                    finish();
                }
            }, 1000);
        }
    }
</script>

<div id="container" onload="handleTime()">
    <span id="timer">Link will generated After </span><span id="time">10</span> Seconds</span>
</div>
```

This will get the number of seconds into a variable and decrease it in each second until it reaches 0. When it reaches 0, your link will be generated into the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Try this below code and let me know.

This one developed by using javascript and it's working for me

```
window.onload = function() {
countDown('my_div1', '<a href="cdtl.html">Hello 1</a>', 720);
}
function countDown(elID, output, seconds) {
var elem = document.getElementById(elID),
    start = new Date().getTime(), end = start+seconds*1000,
    timer = setInterval(function() {
        var now = new Date().getTime(), timeleft = end-now, timeparts;
        if( timeleft < 0) {
            elem.innerHTML = output;
            clearInterval(timer);
        }
        else {
            timeparts = [Math.floor(timeleft/60000),Math.floor(timeleft/1000)%60];
            if( timeparts[1] < 10) timeparts[1] = "0"+timeparts[1];
            elem.innerHTML = "Time left: "+timeparts[0]+":"+timeparts[1];
        }
    },250); // the lower this number, the more accurate the timer. 250 recommended
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick and easy solution:

To display the output of the jQuery/Javascript:

```
<span id="link"></span>
```

The jQuery/Javascript itself:

```
function countdown(){

 var start = 10;                           // start of countdown in seconds
 var link  = 'http://www.example.com/';    // link to display

 if($('#link').text() < 1){                // check if the text of the span-element
  $('#link').text(start);                  // with id #link is a number. if not, put the
 }                                         // value of var start in this element

 setTimeout(function(){                    // start a timeout event

  var current = $('#link').text() - 1;     // get text of #link and reduce it by one 
                                           // and make it a variable with name "current"
  if(current > 0){                         // if var current is higher than 0 execute the
   countdown();                            // function one more time
  }else{                                   // if not, set var link as var current
   current = '<a href="' + link + '">' + link + '</a>';
  }

  $('#link').html(current);                // output var current into span element #link

 }, 1000);                                 // 1000 = 1 second

}

$(document).ready(function(){

 countdown();                              // execute function on page load

});
```